# Yii2- Undefined variable: modelsTraiffSlabs

Tags: php, model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I am working on `Yii2`. I am creating a `dynamic form` using [wbraganca
/
yii2-dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform). I have followed these [steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqFpTBr323Y) and tried to create it.

**Controller**

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new MdcTariff();
    $modelsTraiffSlabs = [new MdcTariffSlabs()];
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsTariffSlabs' => (empty($modelsTraiffSlabs)) ? [new MdcTariffSlabs()] : $modelsTraiffSlabs
    ]);
}
```

**Create View**

```
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model MdcTariff */
/* @var $modelsTraiffSlabs MdcTariffSlabs */
<section class="content">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">

<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'modelsTariffSlabs' => $modelsTraiffSlabs,
]) ?>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```

When I try to open my form I am getting this

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined variable: modelsTraiffSlabs
```

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Try to var_dump($modelsTraiffSlabs) into your controller

Comment: _Side note:_ Isn't the check `empty($modelsTraiffSlabs)` completely pointless? You are literally setting `$modelsTraiffSlabs = [new MdcTariffSlabs()];` before that check so it would never be empty at that point.

Comment: @Sfili_81 it's returning `array(1) { [0]=> object(common\models\MdcTariffSlabs)#131 (10) { ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> NULL .....`

Comment: You pass the value as `modelsTariffSlabs` but are trying to use `modelsTraiffSlabs`. See the difference? `Tariff` vs `Traiff`. You misspell `Tariff` as `Traiff` in all you variables but pass them with the correct spelling. Voting to close this as a typo-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just error 'modelsT**rai**ffSlabs' => 'modelsT**ari**ffSlabs'