# Yii-2 dynamic form model update not working

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, dynamicform

I have created a dynamic form via using the widget [wbraganca
/
yii2-dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform). I am able to create a record but when I try to update it, it's giving me an error. Below is my `actionUpdate`

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelsTariffSlabs = [new MdcTariffSlabs()];


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsTariffSlabs, 'id', 'id');
        $modelsTariffSlabs = CustomtariffModel::createMultiple(MdcTariffSlabs::classname(), $modelsTariffSlabs);
        CustomtariffModel::loadMultiple($modelsTariffSlabs, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsTariffSlabs, 'id', 'id')));

        // validate all models
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = CustomtariffModel::validateMultiple($modelsTariffSlabs) && $valid;

        if ($valid) {
            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    if (! empty($deletedIDs)) {
                        MdcTariffSlabs::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                    }
                    foreach ($modelsTariffSlabs as $modelTariffSlabs) {
                        $modelTariffSlabs->t_id = $model->id;
                        if (! ($flag = $modelTariffSlabs->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        }


        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsTariffSlabs' => (empty($modelsTariffSlabs)) ? [new MdcTariffSlabs()] : $modelsTariffSlabs
    ]);
}
```

**Create View**

```
<section class="content">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">

<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'modelsTariffSlabs' => $modelsTariffSlabs,
]) ?>

</div>
</div>
```

**_form**

```
  <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsTariffSlabs[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'slab_name',
                    'slab_start',
                    'slab_end',
                    'rate'
                ],
            ]); ?>
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
 <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
```

**Error**

When I try to update I am getting below error

```
Undefined variable: modelsTariffSlabs
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2- Undefined variable: modelsTraiffSlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911855/yii2-undefined-variable-modelstraiffslabs)

Comment: @Sfili_81 I did post this question but it's for creating a new record. The same is for updates. and now I am getting it again. although there is no typo.

Comment: why you assign model => $modelsTariffSlabs[0] ? is $modelsTariffSlabs an array of models?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I just followed the tutorial

Comment: You have to debug your code to check if $modelsTariffSlabs[0] is setted when you use it

Comment: @Faisal can you show update.php view file code

Comment: @YatinMistry yes i figured it out